# updateOptions and strokeWidth

Tags: dygraphs

Updating a dygraphs like: `g1.updateOptions({series:1, strokeWidth:2 });` updates all series with a `strokeWidth` of 2.  Is it possible to use `updateOptions` to update just one series with a wider `strokeWidth`?

Comment: Ok - that does work - but I cannot get the following to work:

var sname = 'SERIES NUM1';
g1.updateOptions({series:{sname: {strokeWidth: 2 } }});

Thank you so much for this library - and all your efforts and your response.

bf

Comment: Ok - that does work - but I cannot get the following to work:

var sname = 'SERIES NUM1';
g1.updateOptions({series:{sname: {strokeWidth: 2 } }});

Thank you so much for this library - and all your efforts and your response.

Comment: I figured it out - the below works.  Thanks - bf

g1.updateOptions({series:{[pt]: {strokeWidth: 2 } }});

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`strokeWidth`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#strokeWidth) can be set on a [per-series](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/per-series) basis:

```js
g1.updateOptions({
  series: {
    'y1': {
      strokeWidth: 2
    }
  }
});
```

"y1" is the name of your series. This shows up when you mouse over the chart and usually comes from the first row of your CSV file.